# How do i print arguments in reverse order in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I was trying to write a script that print the arguments in reverse order.
So if I type bash reverse.sh one two three 
I expect my output to be three two one
How can i do this?
This is what I tried and it obviously didn't work...

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
a="$"
for word in $*; do
  echo $a$(($#-i))
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

This is the output i get

```
$3
$2
$1
```

I thought this would print the parameters in order 3, 2, 1 but it didn't. How should I do it? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need `eval` with `echo` i.e. you need to evaluate the expansion, not output it:

```
eval echo $a$(($#-i))
```

Note that, using `eval` in general is discouraged as this could result in security implications if the input string is not sanitized. Check [John1024's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40080215/3789550) answer to see how this can be done without `eval`.

Comment: Please don't recommend `eval` for tasks that do not require it.

Comment: @chepner Right. I would have removed the answer if not accepted, added a note.

Answer (score 6):

Let's define your arguments:

```
$ set -- one two three
```

Now, let's print them out in reverse order:

```
$ for ((i=$#;i>=1;i--)); do echo "${!i}"; done
three
two
one
```

#### How it works

`for ((i=$#;i>=1;i--))` starts a loop in which `i` counts down from `$#` to 1.  For each value of `i`, we print the corresponding positional parameter by `${!i}`.  The construct `${!i}` uses *indirection*: instead of returning the value of `i`, `${!i}` returns the value of the variable whose name is `$i`.

#### As a script

In a multi-line script form, we can use:

```
$ cat reverse 
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=$#;i>=1;i--))
do
   echo "${!i}"
done
```

As an example:

```
$ bash reverse One Two Three
Three
Two
One
```

#### Alternative: using tac

Another way to print things in reverse order is to use the utility `tac`.  Consider this script:

```
$ cat reverse2
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" "$@" | tac
```

Here is an example:

```
$ bash reverse2 Uno Dos Tres
Tres
Dos
Uno
```

`printf "%s\n" "$@"` prints out the positional parameters one per line.  `tac` prints those lines in reverse order.

*Limitation:*  The `tac` method only works correctly if the arguments do not themselves contain newlines.

Comment: The `tac` alternative cannot handle arguments that themselves contain newlines.

Comment: @chepner Good point on the `tac` method.  I updated the answer to note that limitation.

Comment: `tac` is missing on MacOS, it's possible to use `tail -r` as a replacement there